# Using Maven Profiles with a WAR-Packaged Product

Tags: java, maven-2, servlets, maven, war

We have a Maven build (version 2.2.1) that currently produces a WAR file. Our output directory is `target/`, so we end up with a build artifact `target/MyWar.WAR`.

I'm adding two profiles to our POM.xml file to facilitate specific build "flavors" that each require a specific version of an `A.xml` file. In the intermediate build directory `target/MyWar/` there are 3 files:

```
A.xml
A_1.xml
A_2.xml
```

Building in Maven without a specified profile should use A.xml, and it does currently. I want to use `maven-antrun-plugin` to (for Profile 1) replace A.xml with A_1.xml, and for Profile 2 replace A.xml with A_2.xml. (Removing the _1 and _2 suffixes.)

This is an example of Profile 1's execution:

```
<profile>
<id>Profile1</id>
<build>
...
    <execution>
        <id>Profile1-Replace</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <delete
                    file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/../MyWar/A.xml" />
                <copy
                    file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/../MyWar/A_1.xml"
                    tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/../MyWar/A.xml" />
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
...
</build>
</profile>
```

This correctly replaces the files in the intermediate target/MyWar/ directory, but for whatever reason the final WAR that's being produced in `target` does **not** reflect these changes.

It's as if running in the 'package' phase is too late, and the WAR has already been built. Changing the phase to 'compile' or 'test', the immediately-previous phases, complain because the A.xml file (and the intermediate build directory) have not even been created yet.

Comment: Maven 2 or Maven 1?  Which version if Maven 2?  I believe in recent versions of Maven 2 the order of your plugins in the <build> element determines the order that plugins will run when they are in the same phase.

Comment: Maven 2.2.1, updated my question.

Comment: Maybe you could keep one copy of the A.xml file, but use resource filtering (http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html), instead of profiles, to get the desired effect?

Comment: The problem with the resource filtering is that I run the webapp in Eclipse for development, so I can't leave variables in any of the files even pre-release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the *process-resources* phase instead, or even *generate-resources*, if you feel that is a better fit.  As a last resort, use *prepare-package*.  But the *package* phase is the wrong place to do this sort of thing.  All such modifications might typically occur directly in the source tree.

However, if you do the file manipulation in a separate directory, then you can add it during the *package* phase using the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>A_variant</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Of course if you need to go this route, it would be simpler to keep three directories and choose the appropriate one in your profile.

Comment: Tried that, the problem is the intermediate directory (that is compressed to create the WAR) isn't created until sometime *after* the prepare-package phase, but before the *package* phase. So running in the prepare-package phase fails because the XML file doesn't yet exist, and running in the package phase fails because the WAR has already been created.

Comment: @craig I added some details to clarify that I meant the source tree - or how you can selectively choose which one to include by adding webResources.  If you go that route, I wouldn't bother manipulating the files; I'd just use separate directories, e.g. have Profile2/A.xml instead of A_2.xml.